# doparallel package in caret train model under linux

Tags: r, linux, r-caret, doparallel

I have a problem when I run the train function in caret with parallel processing, for example, when I run a simple R code like:

```
   library(doParallel); cl <- makeCluster(4); 
   registerDoParallel(cl)
   require(caret);data(BloodBrain);              
   set.seed(123)
   fit1 <- train(bbbDescr, logBBB, "knn"); fit1
   stopCluster(cl); registerDoSEQ();
```

I get this error message

```
  Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
  worker initialization failed: there is no package called ‘caret’
```

I installed last vesion of caret under R 3.3.0.

I installed the R version and caret version on windows, it is work.

any one have any suggestion about this??

Comment: Not reproducible with Ubuntu 16.04 and the latest R Version 3.3.2. Perhaps you should update your R version.